# Problems in CygWin accessing /dev/nul as non-privileged user

Tags: bash, cygwin, user-accounts

> NOTE: This question is originally a simple typographic mistake
>   (`nul`instead of `null`) for the questioner. Anyway, the details could
>   be useful for anyone having the same error and arriving here after a
>   research. Remember: the problem is not exactly in the user privileges.

I have tried to open a **CygWin's Bash shell** via SSH login with a **limited** (not belonging to the Administrators group) user's account, and tested:

```
$ echo "test" > /dev/nul
bash: /dev/nul: Permission denied
```

This problem does not happen with Administrator account.
I have read through the web that CygWin has **difficulties to run with a limited user's account**, but I have not found any workaround for this.
Does anyone know if there is an available solution?

EDIT: Thanks to @DanielB, now I know the problem was a simple typo: `nul` instead of `null`. So the question should now be:

#### Why an admin user doesn't have this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct device name is `/dev/null`. This is what's causing your issue.

#### Update

Well, as for the admin problem – it's simply a permission thing. Although I'm not so sure it's admin-related.

`stat /dev` reveals the following:

```
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1001/   fuzzy)   Gid: (  513/    None)
```

Where `fuzzy` is my account name. This means my account (and only my account) actually has write permissions in `/dev`.

Using a non-existent redirection target automatically creates it. The results are as follows:

```
$ echo bla > /dev/null
$ file /dev/null
/dev/null: character special
$ echo bla > /dev/nul
$ file /dev/nul
/dev/nul: ASCII text
```

As you can see, this results in a regular file being created in `/dev`. This file also actually stores what's pushed into it and as such consumes disk space.

Comment: OMG, I am an idiot. Thanks, @DanielB. This is what could happen when you do too much windows and linux cross-scripting. :-)

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez Please see the updated answer.

Comment: It is clear now, @DanielB: the problem was not about user permissions in shell. It is a curious thing how a simple typo can drive you for so wrong roads in your researchs to solve a problem.  I have reworded the original question so it could become useful for the forum, instead of a dumb's babble. Thanks again.